# Giving full path of file to a verilog parameter

Tags: verilog

I have a parameter "cdefile" in my code whose value is the filename

parameter cdefile = "memory.hexraw"

This file is generated on the fly during compilation in the same directory where the verilog file resides. I'm using this memory.hexraw file inside module for reading/writing the memory. However, the file is not being able to open by the verilog simulator during simulation. I tried giving the full path

parameter cdefile = "/home/mem/testbench/memory.hexraw" then the verilog simulator is able to read the contents of file and the output is as expected

I don't want to give the full path to the filename as the paths are dynamics and they change for each testbench run. how do I give the $pwd path to the memory.hexraw file inside parameter. pls help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link to the file from the current working directory to the actual file, or copy it into the current working directory. Another thing you can do is pass the full path to the file  on the command line. You can use a concatenation fir the PWD

```
parameter cdefile = {`PWD, "memory.hexraw"}
```